# Lambda node js error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

If I use the node js file which I have downloaded from github it works perfectly.

But if I change the file (even if I just add one single space). I get this below error. Any idea why is this happening?

```
{
 "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
 "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
   "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
   "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
   "require (internal/module.js:12:17)"
 ]
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual code and knowing your lambda configuration. Does the code depend on some node modules? How is the lambda code pushed? Is it through a zip file, s3 or code in-line? Following info would help:

1. Code you downloaded from github which works.
2. AWS Lambda configuration screenshot

Comment: @NeerajSharma Thanks. I am following this sample.
https://www.bypeopletechnologies.com/blog/2017/05/01/serverless-image-resizing-aws-lambda-and-aws-s3/

It works if I upload the same file. But If I add a space in the in the js file. I get the above error.

I am not sure why is this happening. As without any changes to this file, It works perfectly.

Comment: You cannot change the JS file in-line in AWS Console, because you uploaded a zip file. You should follow these steps if you want to change the code:
1. uncompress in your laptop
2. change the code
3. create a zip file with proper dependencies
4. upload the zip file 

Is this how you are making the change?

Comment: @NeerajSharma Yes, thats what i did. I have unzipped the file in my laptop. Change the js file. Zip it back and re-upload the zip file to lambda .

I have just added a extra space to test this. So the dependencies are still same.

Comment: When you get that error, export the function and see what the result looks like. If you have something like prettifier that will rewrite your code, that could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have to named your main file as **index.js**, and it should contains the next code:

> exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
>   callback(null, "Success")};

Probably, when you uploaded your file from GitHub, it had another name.